# How to load a file into target RAM during an STM32CubeIDE debug session

Tags: stm32, gdbserver, segger-jlink

My environment is STM32CubeIDE on Windows 10 with a JLink debug pod.

The device being debugged accumulates data over time and stores it to an external RAM.  When enough data (about 1 MB) is acquired the data is processed.  I can create a binary representation of the data in a file and (using the Segger Jlink Commander's loadfile command) I can write the data to the RAM.

My problem is that if STM32CubeIDE is using the JLink pod to debug the STM32 code, then using JLink Commander to write the data causes STM32CubeIDE to lose connection (two programs trying to use the pod at once is probably the problem.)

Is there a way to have STM32CubeIDE write a file to the target memory?  Maybe some kind of GDB command to write to memory from a file?

The data is too large to fit in the Flash of the STM32 part I am using and the memory is not available until a fairly complex setup sequence is performed (HyperRAM).

A way to keep STM32CubeIDE from aborting the debug session despite the "interruption" of having Commander writing to the HyperRAM would also be a solution if I could figure out how to do it.